# Azure site recovery- Disk size

Tags: azure, diskspace, disaster-recovery

I have a scenario in which I need to fail over SQL server that is on-premises with disks larger than 2 TB. I know ASR does not support that. So, I am trying to find out if I could possibly do a workaround by striping the disks etc.

For ex: I could do a striping of disks on the on-prem machine and then do a failover. However that would require me to pull the machine off line which I cannot afford to.

So, please let me know of a possible workaround or if there is a feature in ASR that I am not aware of.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use either Dynamic disks or  Storage Spaces to create a scenario where you replicate a volume of over 1023GB in size. The only problem is, the single disk cannot be larger than 1023GB and you would have to honor the maximum capacity of the VM (the VM's in Azure are limited by the amount of data disks you can attach).